# What does "Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin" mean?

Tags: android, eclipse

I get that error message quite often when debugging my android app. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really need to improve your problem description if you want a good answer.

The authorities attribute on the provider element in the Manifest.xml is apparently not providing the proper information.
Could you post what the provider definition in your Manifest.xml so we have something to work with?
I believe what is needed is an authority on the provider element in the Manifest.xml.
The authority names a uri which is used to interrogate content providers.
The content provider interrogation calls the content providers getType method.
I may be something like this:

```
 <provider android:name=".provider.XyzProvider"
            android:authorities="android.server.checkin"/>
```

It may also be the path to the provider specified on the name attribute.

Comment: @phreed +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having this message while using JQuery Mobile and didn't filling href on `<a>` tags. I've solved that by filling a href="#" on all `<a>` html tags. See [Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606717/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-android-server-checkin)