# Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-contentprovider

I am having this error running my application on Android 2.1. It makes phonegap navigation stop working. Running on Android 2.2 and later this error doesn't show up and everything works properly.

LogCat shows the error:

> 03-07 21:06:59.495: E/ActivityThread(611): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
>
> 03-07 21:06:59.495: W/Checkin(611): Can't update stat BROWSER_SNAP_CENTER: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats

I've searched about declaring providers on AndroidManifest.xml, but I don't think that's the solution because the same app works fine on Android 2.2.

These topics ( [What does "Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698295/what-does-failed-to-find-provider-info-for-android-server-checkin-mean) and [Failed to find provider info for android.server.provider.checkin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187750/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-android-server-provider-checkin-error)) says to use authorities on the provider element, but I don't have a provider element and don't know if I really need it. My problem is that my mobile app must support Android 2.1 too.

I am using Phonegap 1.4.1 and jQuery.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. In my case, I was using jQuery Mobile's live function to navigate, so most of my  html tags wasn't with href attribute filled.

After filled all of them like below, android.server.checkin message didn't show anymore:

> `<a href="#"></a>`

Thx anyway!